# Nodejs and React inside docker containers

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run Node/React project inside Docker containers. I have a NodeJS server for the API's and the client app. I also have `concurrently` installed and everything works fine when running `npm run dev`.

This issue is when I run the server and app via a `docker-compose.yml` file I get the following error from the client:

`client      | [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/current_user from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:5000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)`

Here is the **docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  frontend:
    container_name: client
    build:
      context: ./client
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: client
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./client:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - local
  backend:
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: server
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - frontend
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    networks:
      - local
networks:
  local:
    driver: bridge
```

**Server Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 5000

# You can change this
CMD [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

**Client Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:lts-slim

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I am using `"http-proxy-middleware": "^0.21.0"` so my `setupProxy.js` is

```
const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(proxy('/auth/google', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
    app.use(proxy('/api/**', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
};
```

Comment: Looks like your backend service running on port 5000 didn't map correctly to local machine host. Is your services running on port 5000 after container is started via docker-compose? If yes can you please share the logs( or screenshot) of docker-compose up command?

Comment: I don't think Aditya replacing localhost with container_name will work. Reason is we are requesting to backend server from client browser (front end application) which don't know what is http://<container_name>:5000 is. This works very well when we have backend to backend connection like in some microservices.

Comment: I see, just noticed, probably he needs to add 0.0.0.0:5000 at host side because he is using bridge network.

Comment: Here is a link to the docker-compose output https://docs.google.com/document/d/1HG_0xG0glTs0MDqmgMpufsVvofKsKwn8hDUhWVFFNzg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use **container_name** instead of localhost

```
    app.use(proxy('/auth/google', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
    app.use(proxy('/api/**', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }));
```

You can also check these details by inspecting your network using following command:-

```
docker inspect <network_name>
```

It will show all the connected containers to the network, also the host names created for those containers.

> NOTE : Host names are created based on container_names otherwise based
>   on service names.

Comment: That didn't work. Got the same error  "client      | [HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/current_user from localhost:3000 to http://container_name:5000 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)"

Comment: My bad @teej, first check using docker ps command if both containers are running.

Comment: Here is the docker inspect output https://docs.google.com/document/d/1b4PIwkeCR7zjdfZqIt0A8UBf4P02iF0K3dYxMfPk_nE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This means both containers are running, you had to use "server:5000" not "container_name:5000"

Comment: "container_name" = to the name of container you are trying to connect from back-end i.e its "server" in your case.

Comment: Also, if your code is for frontend application and get's called from browser, above won't work and you can try using either 127.0.0.1:5000 and then 172.22.0.1 which is host ip address from inside container

Comment: That was it. Thanks.

Comment: Let me know, what solved your problem I will accordingly add details to my answer.

Comment: Also if you are satisfied with the answer, kindly accept it so others can benefit from it as well. thanks.

Comment: It was the "you had to use "server:5000" not "container_name:5000" part that fixed it.